# Can't read <appSetting> value from my ASP.NET web.config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to retrieve a value from my `<appSettings>` section in my `web.config` file. The key is named `imgServer`.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Label1.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("imglServer");
```

I then tried:

```
Label1.Text = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["imgServer"];
```

But this doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ConfigurationSettings was depreciated in favor for ConfigurationManager.

Comment: When you say "failed"...how did it fail? Was there a compilation error or a runtime error? You should post any exceptions you encounter into questions that helps us narrow down the cause greatly. Are you using VB or C#, in future you should specify which?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Appsettings.Get("imglServer");
```

Try that.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["imgServer"];


    } --THIS doe not return with the value, but loads the page at least, so still unsure how to get the value from web.config

Comment: That's what I'm saying, try: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { label1.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("imgServer"); }

Comment: Thanks Brian. I was looking at the wrong web.config, which was why I got nothing in return. Your code works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what version of ASP.NET you're using or which language:

In C# it would be:

```
Label1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imgServer"];
```

You might also have to add a `using System.Configuration;` in the `using`s section of your class file or code-behind.

In VB.NET it'd be:

```
Label1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("imgServer")
' Note the round brackets instead of the square brackets as used by C# ^^^
```

You might also have to add a reference to `System.Configuration` if it's not already there.